# Making large SQL statements easier to change in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following code in an application I'm building and to be honest... it feels like a great deal of pain when I want to change something like this. I've always had this problem with SQL in code but never understood how to address it. Is there some way or common practice that would make the SQL here a bit easier to maintain and change? (I've read not to use stored procedures)

```
$stmt_arr = array(
            ':steamid' => isset($playerSummary['steamid']) ? $playerSummary['steamid'] : "",
            ':personaname' => isset($playerSummary['personaname']) ? utf8_encode($playerSummary['personaname']) : "",
            ':community_vis_state' => isset($playerSummary['communityvisibilitystate']) ? $playerSummary['communityvisibilitystate'] : "",
            ':profile_state' => isset($playerSummary['profilestate']) ? $playerSummary['profilestate'] : "NULL",
            ':profile_url' => isset($playerSummary['profileurl']) ? $playerSummary['profileurl'] : "",
            ':avatar_url' => isset($playerSummary['avatar']) ? $playerSummary['avatar'] : "",
            ':avatar_medium' => isset($playerSummary['avatarmedium']) ? $playerSummary['avatarmedium'] : "",
            ':avatar_full' => isset($playerSummary['avatarfull']) ? $playerSummary['avatarfull'] : "",
            ':shallow_update' => $isFriend
        );          
        $stmt = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`steamid`, `personaname`, `community_visibility_state`, "
                . "`profile_state`, `profile_url`, `avatar_url`, `avatar_medium_url`, `avatar_full_url`, `last_updated`, `shallow_update`)"
                . " VALUES (:steamid, :personaname, :community_vis_state, :profile_state, :profile_url, "
                . ":avatar_url, :avatar_medium, :avatar_full, NOW(), :shallow_update) "
                . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `steamid` = VALUES(`steamid`), "
                . "`personaname` = VALUES(`personaname`), "
                . "`community_visibility_state` = VALUES(`community_visibility_state`), "
                . "`profile_state` = VALUES(`profile_state`), "
                . "`profile_url` = VALUES(`profile_url`), "
                . "`avatar_url` = VALUES(`avatar_url`), "
                . "`avatar_medium_url` = VALUES(`avatar_medium_url`), "
                . "`avatar_full_url` = VALUES(`avatar_full_url`), "
                . "`last_updated` = VALUES(`last_updated`),"
                . "`shallow_update` = VALUES(`shallow_update`)");
        $stmt->execute($stmt_arr);
```

Comment: and by easier how do you mean? Do you want it so that any more items you add to the array automatically get generated into the SQL Query?

Comment: By the way, you do not need quotes on each line and concatenation.  PHP supports multiline strings - just open the doublequote on the first line, then new-lines as required and close double-quotes at the end.

Comment: @AleksG oh ok thanks - that's a good start.

Comment: In fact I might just be complaining about nothing. Without the concatenation it's actually not so bad

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
function pdo_insert($con, $table, $data_arr)
{
    if (!is_array($data_arr) || !count($data_arr)) return false;

    $bind = ':'.implode(',:', array_keys($data_arr));

    $sql  = 'INSERT into '.$table.'('.implode(',', array_keys($data_arr)).') '.
          'values ('.$bind.')';
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $status = $stmt->execute(array_combine(explode(',',$bind), array_values($data_arr)));

    if($status)
    {
      // success
      $msg = 'Data added to database successfully';
      return $msg;
    }
    else
    {
      // failure
      $msg = 'Error in adding data into database';
      return $msg;
    }
}
```

Calling the function

```
$msg = pdo_insert($db, 'table name here', $_POST);

// see the result
echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateSQL($table, $arr) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table . " (";
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        $sql .= "`".substr_replace($k, "", 0, 1)."`, ";
    }
    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -2);
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        $sql .= $k.", ";
    }
    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -2);
    $sql .= ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        $sql .= "`".substr_replace($k, "", 0, 1)."` = VALUES(`".substr_replace($k, "", 0, 1)."`), ";
    }
    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -2);

    return $sql;
}

print_r(generateSQL("user", $stmt_arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read not to use stored procedure ?

They are the solution to your problem, when queries get complex, it is better to move the logic to a sotored procedure and just execute it (e.g `CALL sp_isnert_user ?, ?`)

They also allow you to maintain/modify your SQL logic without really touching your code.